# Why is $i_y \circ T = T^{**} \circ i_x$ for a bounded operator in a normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $T : X \to Y$ be a bounded operator between normed spaces. $i_X: X \to X^{**}$ means the canonical embedding in the  double dual space

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1670873/477927) uses the commutativity of the following diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>i_X>>X^{**} \\
@VTVV @VVT^{**}V \\
Y @>>i_Y> Y^{**},
\end{CD}

I understand the fin-dim case.
I would like to know is there any more checking needed in comparison with a finite-dimensional case?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/384786/477927) the case of a finite dimension is treated

Comment: I don't think there is anything specific to the finite-dimensional case in the answers you cite.

Comment: @Idéophage Looks like that. Even boundedness doesn't appear to be essential.

Comment: Yes, it's really just a set-theoretic manipulation, nothing specific to linear algebra even.